# How to run ASP.NET MVC Core Web application in the virtual folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, iis-express

I have a solution with regular ASP.NET MVC Web application project and ASP.NET MVC Core Web application project. Regular MVC is set as a startup project. IIS Express is configured to run Core application in virtual folder:

```
<site name="MVC" id="2">
    <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
      <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Users\user\source\repos\MVC\MVC" />
    </application>
    <application path="/core" applicationPool="Core AppPool">
      <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Users\user\source\repos\MVC\Core" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
      <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:11686:localhost" />
      <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44313:localhost" />
    </bindings>
  </site>
```

But when I'm going to https://localhost:44313/core I'm getting **HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden. The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.**

If I change solution settings to run with multiple startup projects both applications are starting perfectly fine. I'm just not able to run .Net core application in virtual folder.

Comment: Set up two sites and then use a reverse proxy to merge the URLs.

Comment: How to do that in IIS Express?

Comment: Are both application independent?

Comment: Yes, they are both independent.